# Browser sync isn't serving the root files

Tags: javascript, gulp, browser-sync, gulp-browser-sync

Browser sync isn't serving the root files using gulp.

this is my code:

```
 gulp.task("liveReload", [
  "copy", "watch"
], function () {

  browserSync.init(null,{
    server: {
      baseDir: ["public"]
    },
    files: ["*"],
    port: 8080
  });
  gulp.watch("src/index.html").on("change",browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch("src/**/*.html").on("change",browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch(paths.srcJS, browserSync.reload);
});
```

I tried to play with the browser sync options and nothings works. it's only serving the subFolder files.

> Is pointing the index.html but isn't serving it. which mean no liveReload occurred while changing to index.html

Comment: Is your copy function actually copying the files to the destination "public" folder ?

Comment: @jmtalarn yes sure & The sub-folders files is working well

Answer (score 0):

[too much for a comment]:

```
gulp.watch("src/index.html").on("change",browserSync.reload);
gulp.watch("src/**/*.html").on("change",browserSync.reload);
```

are redundant (since the globstar `**` matches 0 or more directories - here you apparently have 0 directories between `src` and `index.html`).  The first watch is included in the second so maybe browserSync is getting confused.  Try removing the first, leaving only

```
gulp.watch("src/**/*.html").on("change",browserSync.reload);
```

and see if that helps.  [** globstar docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob#glob-primer).

Also try:

```
baseDir: "public"
```

or

```
baseDir: "./public"
```

instead of

```
baseDir: ["public"]
```

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks for your answer. You are right, `("src/**/*.html")`  is sufficient. but `brwoserSync.reload` is for what the serve is listening for reloading that why doesn't solve my issue

Comment: But if you remove the first one ('src/index.html') does it still not work?

Comment: I remove the first line and still not work. If you got o subDir it will work well

Comment: See my additional suggestion in the my answer above.

Comment: Hello. Please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Hello it wasn't bowser sync issue. the index.html was added after the browser sync serving. That why I gonna close this question. Thanks.